# How to customise a MudBlazor Component

Tags: css, blazor, font-size, mudblazor, mudselect

So I have a this MudBlazor `<MudSelect />` Component and I want to change its display font to .75rem. (Below doesn't work!)

```
<MudSelect style="font-size: .75rem!;" T="string" MultiSelection="true" ...
```

So after the chosen values are selected, and displayed, I would like that text to be much smaller than the default.

I have been struggling with this change, and now wonder if it's possible and if so how?

Or any similar form of component customisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the `.mud-select-input` CSS class.

```
<style>
    .change-only-this .mud-select-input{
    font-size:.75rem;
    }
</style>

<MudSelect Class="change-only-this" T="string" Label="CustomStyle" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Tyrannosaur")" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Henon Rex")" />
</MudSelect>
```

In the example above, I add `change-only-this` class to the `MudSelect` so that only that component is modified.

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wumRuiPbIvxYCHwK)

Comment: Yes, that worked, but could you explain a little bit on how you found this out? As in how did you know this ?

Comment: @Choco I used the browser dev tools Elements tab, to see what the components html elements and their CSS classes are.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to simply capitalize the `Style` attribute?

```
<MudSelect Style="font-size: .75rem!;" T="string" MultiSelection="true" ...
```

https://mudblazor.com/api/select#properties

Comment: Yep, didn't seem to do anything!